# rails add variables to mappings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following mapping in my controller (`@initial_matches` represents an SQL query). I want to attach a variable to each `|listing|` -- for example, let's say I want to add a score based on some criteria and attach it to each and then refer to it in my view. Is there a way to do that?

```
 @refined_list = @initial_matches.map { |listing|
      listing_location = MultiGeocoder.geocode(listing.location)
      listing_location.distance_from(user_location, :units=>:miles) > distance.to_f ? nil : listing
      @new_variable = listing.some_criteria //NOT WORKING
    }.compact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@new_variable` is being overwritten each time through the loop. This type of thing would be better placed in your model; create a method on your Listing model that computes the score based on the model's attributes, and call that in your view.

Comment: Hm that might work -- although the score is based on the current logged in user, so I'm not sure if that would work in the listing model....would it?

Comment: Sure it would, just pass the current user into the call:  `listing.compute_score(@current_user)`

Comment: hm, I'll have to research this, i wouldn't really know where to start, I'm new to this >.< -- can I just move the mapping I have in my question to the model or would that not work